# How to send multiple API request to vuex store from nuxt-middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to send multiple API calls to vuex store from nuxt-middleware. I have tried for single api and works perfectly fine but how to access for multiple API?

```
// middlewear/log.js

import axios from 'axios';

export default function ( {store} ) {
return axios.get(`http://my/api`)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        store.commit('add', response.data);
    });
}
```

I tried following way but it didn't work. Please anyone could help me ?

```
import axios from 'axios';
async asyncData( {store} ){
    return axios.all([
        axios.get('http://my/api'),
        axios.get('http://my/api2')
    ]).then(axios.spread((first, second) => {
        return {
            store.commit('add', first.data);
            store.commit('sub', second.data);
            // posts: first.data,
            // total: second.data
        }
    })).catch((err) => {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: err.message })
    })

}
```

Comment: How it didn't work? What errors?

Comment: it worked now simply commiting to store without return

Answer (score 0):

Hey in my case it worked absolute fine when you remove the second return

```
import axios from 'axios';
async asyncData( {store} ){
    return axios.all([
        axios.get('http://my/api'),
        axios.get('http://my/api2')
    ]).then(axios.spread((first, second) => {
            store.commit('add', first.data);
            store.commit('sub', second.data);
            // posts: first.data,
            // total: second.data
    })).catch((err) => {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: err.message })
    })

}
```